# Cannot using assistant editor connect the Table Cell UI to Code

Tags: ios, swift

I am following the offical [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH8-SW1) tutorial for creating iOS application,

In Step `Connect the Table Cell UI to Code` for Connect MealTableViewCell.swift with Table View Cell

I following the tutorial to open assistant editor, and try to find `MealTableViewCell.swift`, but only `UIResponder.h` is displayed instead of `MealTableViewCell.swift`.

Like following image on my computer:
[image]

I have proper set the Class:

[image]

It should be like this in the tutorial:

[image]

Comment: 1. Try tapping some other ui component in xib/storyboard and then selecting the cell again. 2. Make sure you have provided the class name correct in Identity Inspector. If it still doesnt work, it means it has not yet indexed the classes properly. try quitting xcode.

Comment: Close the current Storyboard and re-open or close all open tabs and re-open.

Comment: @AjinkyaSharma I have proper set the Class name

Comment: @AmirKhan, Not work even I restart the Xcode

Comment: Try tapping on the arrow beside you Mealtableviewcell in identity inspector and see if it takes you to the class. Else instead of opening it not through assistant editor, but -> Cmd+shift+o, type class name, and then press ctrl+option+enter

Comment: Did you setup a Swift project rather than SwiftUI?

Answer (score 5):

1. Set Cell class
2. Select Table Cell "Content View"
3. Click on "Automatic" you see line with cell class

Assistant editor connect the Table Cell UI to Code

[image]

Comment: That has really worked. It appears now in the Breadcrumbs-navigation.